# Php - Amazon s3 how do I check my connection is success or not

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using amazon-php-sdk. In my application I'm accepting key and secret value from a form and passing for connecting to Aws. Here is my code.

```
<?php
require 'aws-autoloader.php';
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
try {
    $s3Client = S3Client::factory(array(
        'key' => 'my key',
        'secret' => 'my secret key'
    ));
}
catch(S3Exception $e) {

   echo 'Msg' . $e->getMessage();
} 
?>
```

1. How do I check whether the connection is success or not ?
2. How can I check the already created object using the passed key so I that I don't want to create the object again. I need to create the object only if the passed key is different from the already created one.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/quick-start.html#detecting-and-handling-errors

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/namespace-Aws.S3.Exception.html

Comment: I have updated my code. Its not reaching in the catch block even if I give wrong keys.

Comment: exit( 'Msg' . $e->getMessage()); you have an additional 3 in catch block

Comment: There's no exception, because there's no "connection" to S3 being established.  There is no interaction between your local code and S3 until you actually *do* something, make some kind of actual request.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Michael pointed out, you have to make an actual request to check the connection.AWS discourages any unnecessary validation requests which will affect the performance of your application and your usage bill.

But if you need to validate you can use [ListBucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_listBuckets) or [HEAD](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html) request on a bucket.

Checkout this best practises [article](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/1904).

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';     
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

try {

// Instantiate the S3 client with your AWS credentials
$s3Client = S3Client::factory(array(
    'credentials' => array(
        'key'    => 'YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
        'secret' => 'YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
    )
));

$buckets = $s3Client->listBuckets();


}
catch(Exception $e) {

   exit($e->getMessage());
}
```

To answer your second question.You can use [doesObjectExist](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_doesObjectExist) function which returns a *boolean*.